# Google Natural Language python library has problems predicting when certain words in sentence

Tags: google-cloud-automl

On the portal, I can insert a sentence and get a score back. If I use the python library I get sentences with no scores. Upon further investigation, it turns out a single word (without punctuation) prevents the prediction. If I replace this word with another it works, if I replace it with 2 words it works, if I replace it with "United States" however, which is different from the original word, I also get no sentiment score. None of this is an issue on the portal so either its the python library or the portal is using a different predictor engine.

Anyone run into this before and have a solution. I am going to have to look at their rest interface now as I have lost confidence in the python library

Answer (score 0):

c# library works fine - way to go google for a shoddy python library